the difference of explicit and implicit definition of functions logically
The fundamental analysis book I'm reading has a section on the difference between the implicit and explicit definitions of functions. The implicit definition of a function f specifies what property $ P(x,y) $ links the input x with the output $f(x)$.
How is the implicit definition different from an explicit one, showing how one generates the output $f(x)$ from each input and specifies the domain and range?
Is there a difference between the specificity of the domain and the range? cant the property $P(x,y)$ generate the way the output $f(x)$ is for each input x? is every explicit definition implicit ?
Could someone give me an example highlighting the difference between implicit and explicit Function definition?
thank you for the help

Please use MathJax to typeset the mathematical formulas in your MSE questions. It's easy to learn and makes your questions much easier to read.

@RobArthan hello yes i agree yet there isnt any complicated math formulas in the question only property p and function f . is my question not easy to follow or read?

$f(x)$ looks much, much better than f(x): why not learn good practice sooner rather than later? You would find my answer very hard to read if I hadn't used MathJax.

@RobArthan i do actually know a little Mathjax. I thought the question is readable. as they say no accounting for taste but fair enough it is much more aesthetically pleasing. thank you for the advice

The square root function $\sqrt\, : \Bbb{R}_{\ge0} \to \Bbb{R}_{\ge0}$ is implicitly defined by the property:
$$
{\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}^2 = x
$$
That gives you no information about how to compute $\sqrt{x}$ for a given $x$ but specifies exactly what our requirements on $\sqrt\,$ are. An explicit definition might be:
$$
\sqrt{x} = \sup \{y \mid y^2 \le x\}
$$
or
$$
\sqrt{x} = \exp\left(\frac12\log(x)\right)
$$
This is not about how the range or domain are specified but is about how the value $f(x)$ of the function $f$ is specified for a given argument $x$: the explicit definition gives you an equation: $f(x) = \cdots$; while the implicit definition describes something we would like to hold of the function.

thank you this was very helpful in clearing the confusion i had. much appreciated@Rob Arthan
